# Starting an IRC server where only my clients can connect to

Tags: java, android, chat, irc, livechat

I need to start an IRC server but I need to make only the clients I make, able to connect to the server.

Maybe I'm not explaining well enough, I am making an IRC client and I want it to be accessible ONLY through MY client, I don't want other clients like XCHAT ect... to be able to connect to it.

I will be using a username and password combo, but I want the users to connect only through my client...

I've tried searching on google but I've only found username password combo posts... maybe I was using the wrong keywords...

Comment: Are you coding the IRC server as well, or just the client?  If you aren't doing both, what server software are you using?

Comment: I wanted to use an already made server but don't know which, the client is coded by me, however if there's more possibility, I could code the server myself

Comment: Well, until you know what you're using server-side, you can't know for certain what possibilities exist.  What might work for ServerA won't work for ServerB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent other clients, you could simply pass some type of hidden "client password" to the server.

So user submits login password, the client silently sends client password.

You end up with

```
Login
Password
ClientPassword
```

If the ClientPassword is not correct, don't allow the connection.

Comment: that was one of my options, but wouldn't that be easily spoofable with some reverse engineering? maybe creating the client password dynamically would be the solution?

Comment: You are correct, you could try something like serializing the Login/Password/ClientPassword and then hash the entire transfer. This way you can't pull out just the ClientPassword